# tegrahost_v2: Stat for tegra186-quill-p3310-1000-c03-00-base.dtb failed

Tags: tegra

I've built an image for Jetson TX2 module using yocto. Everything when fine for few days but now I get this error when I try to flash the device.

```
Welcome to Tegra Flash
version 1.0.0
Type ? or help for help and q or quit to exit
Use ! to execute system commands

[   0.0008 ] tegrasign_v2 --key None --getmode mode.txt
[   0.0016 ] Assuming zero filled SBK key
[   0.0016 ] 
[   0.0016 ] Generating RCM messages
[   0.0023 ] tegrarcm_v2 --listrcm rcm_list.xml --chip 0x18 --download rcm mb1_recovery_prod.bin 0 0
[   0.0030 ] RCM 0 is saved as rcm_0.rcm
[   0.0033 ] RCM 1 is saved as rcm_1.rcm
[   0.0033 ] List of rcm files are saved in rcm_list.xml
[   0.0033 ] 
[   0.0033 ] Signing RCM messages
[   0.0040 ] tegrasign_v2 --key None --list rcm_list.xml --pubkeyhash pub_key.key
[   0.0046 ] Assuming zero filled SBK key
[   0.0076 ] 
[   0.0076 ] Copying signature to RCM mesages
[   0.0083 ] tegrarcm_v2 --chip 0x18 --updatesig rcm_list_signed.xml
[   0.0093 ] 
[   0.0093 ] Parsing partition layout
[   0.0100 ] tegraparser_v2 --pt flash.xml.tmp
[   0.0109 ] 
[   0.0109 ] Creating list of images to be signed
[   0.0116 ] tegrahost_v2 --chip 0x18 --partitionlayout flash.xml.bin --list images_list.xml zerosbk
[   0.0124 ] Stat for tegra186-quill-p3310-1000-c03-00-base.dtb failed
[   0.0161 ] 
Error: Return value 4
Command tegrahost_v2 --chip 0x18 --partitionlayout flash.xml.bin --list images_list.xml zerosbk
```

Does this error ring a bell to anyone?

I am able to flash the board with JetPack.

Thanks,

-Damien

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you never figured this out, it looks like

```
[   0.0124 ] Stat for tegra186-quill-p3310-1000-c03-00-base.dtb failed
```

is the real error. Fix that and you should be good.